# Copy Paste table data from a .msg file into separate cells in an Excel worksheet using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a .msg file in which the body contains data in a tabular form. I am trying to copy this data to Excel and preserve the same tabular form. There are 2 columns and multiple rows in this tabular form.

When I do this manually I get each value in a different cell in Excel.

I have below code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim MyOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim x As Namespace
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Path As String
    Set MyOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Set x = MyOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Path = "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Outlook Import\abc.msg"
    Set Msg = x.OpenSharedItem(Path)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Msg.Sender
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2") = Msg.CC
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3") = Msg.To
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A4") = Msg.SentOn
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A5") = Msg.SenderEmailAddress
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A6") = Msg.ReceivedByEntryID
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A7") = Msg.Subject
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A8") = Msg.Body
End Sub
```

This is copying the whole body and pasting it into one cell i.e "A8".

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A8") = Msg.Body
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the email body to be inserted row by row in the document, starting from `Range("A8")`?

This works for me:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim MyOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim x As Namespace
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Path As String
    Dim vItem As Variant

    Set MyOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Set x = MyOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Path = "C:\Test\test.msg" ' change path & name of msg file
    Set Msg = x.OpenSharedItem(Path)

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1") = Msg.Sender
        .Range("A2") = Msg.CC
        .Range("A3") = Msg.To
        .Range("A4") = Msg.SentOn
        .Range("A5") = Msg.SenderEmailAddress
        .Range("A6") = Msg.ReceivedByEntryID
        .Range("A7") = Msg.Subject
        vItem = Split(Msg.Body, Chr(10))
        .Range("A8").Resize(UBound(vItem) - LBound(vItem) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(vItem)
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit #1**

This copies the email `HTMLbody` to the clipboard and pastes it into the document afterwards retaining the column structure:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim MyOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim x As Namespace
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Path As String
    Dim vItem As Variant

    Set MyOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Set x = MyOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Path = "C:\Test\test.msg" ' change path
    Set Msg = x.OpenSharedItem(Path)

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1") = Msg.Sender
        .Range("A2") = Msg.CC
        .Range("A3") = Msg.To
        .Range("A4") = Msg.SentOn
        .Range("A5") = Msg.SenderEmailAddress
        .Range("A6") = Msg.ReceivedByEntryID
        .Range("A7") = Msg.Subject

        ' requires Microsoft Forms 2 Object Library under Tools/References
        With New MSForms.DataObject
            .SetText Msg.HTMLBody
            .PutInClipboard
        End With

        .Range("A8").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) ' change paste type if necessary

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's right. When i do this manually, I open the message file and select the table in it and copy, then I use the normal paste as values in Excel. This gives me two columns of data with each value in separate cells row by row as it is in outlook message body.

Comment: @Frostem How could this give you **two** columns of data unless the body consists of a table with two columns or something, which your post didn't specify? Anyway, did you try my code?

Comment: Hi @Miqi180, I used your code and it does work in separating out the data into different cells but this does not give me the exact similar output structure that i get from manual copy paste. Still this is helpful as this separates the data out in multiple cells. Thank you :)

Comment: @Miqi180 Awesome... This is what i was looking for. Just one questions. Can i paste only values. I do not want any formatting. Again thank you so much for this code. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ Frostem Just add `.UsedRange.ClearFormats` in the next line of code right after `.Range("A8").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)`, provided of course, that you don't require any formatting at all in the worksheet. Otherwise, set a range object with the specific range instead of using `UsedRange`.